# Can't dismiss view controller after presenting from SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skscene

I'm trying to reach a settings screen from `SKScene`.

This is how I present the settings controller:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
let settingController: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Settings") as UIViewController

let vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
vc.presentModalViewController(settingController, animated: true);
```

but once I run this code to dismiss:

```
@IBAction func backToGame(sender : AnyObject) {
    [self.parentViewController .dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)];
}
```

I get `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` error, with nothing shown in the log.

How do I solve this?

Comment: `- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}`

Comment: doesn't seem to work correctly too

Answer (score 1):

I was a fool not knowing I just got confused between objective-C and swift. It seems that the problem came from where I used obj-C instead of swift when my project is suppose to be compiled in swift.

```
@IBAction func backToGame(sender : AnyObject) {
    self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true);
}
```

This solved my problem immediately.